# How do i plot a large dataset (550.000 points) so spikes in the values can be identified?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a dataset of 550.000 points. around 460.000 of them have values in the area of -2 to -30 while the rest has values from 0 to 1550.
I tried plotting them with gnuplot, but the large amount of jumps from minus values and to some of the positive values makes it one big block of lines where I cannot see anything.

So how can I plot these values in a way such that I can identify all the spikes where it goes from negative values and into positive values?

data is a single column of values in a file so it should be fairly simple to parse into any tool (preferably for Linux though, but I can do with Windows as well).

Comment: well, I'm not sure whether displays which are 550'000 pixels wide are available ;-). What about plotting nevertheless with an interactive terminal, e.g. wxt, and then interactively zoom in? Alternatively, you also could use 1 pixel for one datapoint indicating your two ranges, e.g. black (-2 to -30) and yellow (0 to 1550). Then 550'000 datapoints would be an image with a size of 1000x550 pixels. What do you want to do if you have identified these 90'000 values?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you exactly want to do with your 90'000 spikes, here, plotting `with impulses` is probably better than `with lines`. The example below is just with only 20'000 datapoints and approx. 17% spikes.

**Code:**

```
### "find" spikes
reset session

# create some test data
range1(n) = int(rand(0)*28)-30
range2(n) = int(rand(0)*1550)
data(n) = int(rand(0)+0.17) == 0 ? range1(0) : range2(0)
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:20000] { print data(0) }
set print

plot $Data u 1 w impulses notitle

### end of code
```

**Result:** (screen capture of wxt terminal with zoom-in)

[image]